# How to convert URL aliases back to node ID

Tags: uri

I wonder how to convert a URL path back to it's own node (node/nid). I wish to get the original node ID from a given path. e.g.

path = "news/my-news"

..and trace it back to get it's own original URL, e.g. 65. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GokulNK has already [given](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/103123/1899) the answer to use [`drupal_get_normal_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_normal_path/7). If you are working on any path alias that is different than the current path, use that.

If you want to get the non-aliased path of the **current page/path**, simply use `$_GET['q']`. 
Drupal path aliases are mod_rewrites but you still can find the internal path from `$_GET['q']`. 
For node paths or any structured paths and if you want to get the node ID or something, now don't `explode('/', $_GET['q'])` :)

Meet [`arg()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7).

- `Aliased path: content/my-new-page`
- `$_GET['q']: node/69`
- `arg(0) = node`
- `arg(1) = 69`
- `drupal_get_normal_path('content/my-new-page')` (Probably require some db trips unless cached)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [drupal_get_normal_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_normal_path/7) function.

> Return value
>
> The internal path represented by the alias, or the original alias if
>   no internal path was found.

Answer (score 0):

All the URl path are stored in database so you can configure it in 
admin/config/search/path 
whether your are using pathauto or writing your own url alises.
Deleting from admin setting may convert a URL path back to it's own node (node/nid).